# call dictionary from one function to another

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, dictionary

How can I call a dictionary created in one function to another?

I have tried using [How do I access a dictionary from a function to be used in another function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40251960/how-do-i-access-a-dictionary-from-a-function-to-be-used-in-another-function) but it doesn't work for me.

I have created `dictionary1` in `server()` and I want to use it in `create_csv()`.

How can I call it?

```
def server(id):

  dictionary1 = dict(zip(temp_sourcenodes, sip))

  dictionary1.update(dict(zip(temp_destnodes, dip)))

  print(dictionary1)

def create_csv():
```

Comment: Don't use built-ins as variable / argument names, e.g. use `id_` instead of `id`.

Comment: my server functions has other things to do that's y it is needed to define as id

Answer (score 3):

Use `return` and call `server` from within `create_csv`. This may necessitate feeding `id_` to `create_csv`, but this is likely reasonable, as presumably `dictionary1` is constructed based on `id_`.

```
def server(id_):
    # some code to construct dictionary1
    return dictionary1

def create_csv(id_):
    my_dict = server(id_)
    # export to csv here
```

Comment: no the dictionary is not based on id.  temp_sourcenodes and sip are two lists. I am using one as key and other as value.

Comment: @Sakshi, The code will still work irrespective. Otherwise, if the dictionary construction doesn't need `id_`, create it in another function that doesn't require `id_` as an argument.

Comment: @Sakshi, Yet another alternative is to use object-oriented programming to store class-instance-level variables.

Comment: Yes, just make sure you provide all necessary arguments when you call `server`.

Comment: but its not working if i call id in create_csv and i cant remove id from server()